# Создание локализированной копии сайта

Tags: локализация, база-данных

Как локализировать всю информацию сайта-оригинала для русскоязычной версии. Есть  более трёхсот страниц информации. Нет возможности получить исходники оригинального сайта или хотя бы получить дамп БД. Брать каждую страницу, переводить и вносить во вновь созданную базу - далеко не самый простой способ. 
Как решить данную проблему?
Буду рад выслушать любые предложения по решению данной задачи.

Comment: Поддерживаю вариант выше - но выдрать всю страничку и загнать ее в google.translate.api или в яндекс - вы получите некий мусорный контейнер с кучей лексических ошибок - которые со временем все исправятся... в конце концов это 2 работы - а не 300.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая мысль — натравить `wget --recursive`, распарсить HTML, выдирая тела статей, загнать тексты это в базу удобного вида — вот и некий аналог дампа базы. Дальше, наверное, только вручную, иначе получим [грустный институт ран](http://lurkmore.to/Squirrel_institute).